# How to display selected value Form drop down list?

Tags: php, html

I have a list proxy.Once I select and save it I want to display the selected data. How can I do this?.I want to display it in selected list and once I reload or get back to that page `

```
<?php
include_once("../noaccess.php"); 
include_once(CLASS_PATH."fetch_service.php"); 
$objfetch = new fetchService();
include_once(CLASS_PATH."proxy.php");
$objproxy = new Proxy();
include_once(CLASS_PATH."log.php"); 
$objlog= new changelog();
$account_id=$_SESSION['account_id'];
global $mysqli;
if($_POST['submit']=="Save")
{
    $pname=$_POST['proxy'];
    $query="UPDATE `proxy` SET `proxy_default`='1' where `proxyname`='$pname'";
    $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
    $_SESSION['check_update'] = "1";
    setcookie("msg","Proxy Seleted",time()+5,"/");
    header("location:".SITE_URL."index.php?view=default_proxy");
}
?>

<form name="frmcr" id="frmcr" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" id="mode" value="insert" />
<table align="left" id="tblworking_hours" class="tbl_altcolor shadow" style="width:25%;margin-left:30px">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th align="center"><b>Proxy</b></th>
         <td><select name="proxy" id="proxy" class="required input">
               <option value="">Select</option>
               <!--              <option value="<?php echo $i ;?>"<?php echo $i==$ring21 ? "selected":"";?> ><?php echo $i;?></option> -->

               <?php
                    $result = $objfetch->fetch_proxy("*","where account_id='".$_SESSION['account_id']."' ");
                          foreach($result as $key=>$resrproxy)
                          {
                          ?>
               <option value="<?php echo $resrproxy['proxyname'];?>"<?php echo $resrproxy['proxyname']== $resrproxy['proxyname'] ? "selected":"";?>><?php echo $resrproxy['proxyname'];?></option>
               <?php } ?>
            </select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" class="btn" style="margin-left:35px;"/></td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: want to display once I come back to that pager or reload it.In list

Comment: In your code, to show the selected, `<?php echo $resrproxy['proxyname']== $resrproxy['proxyname'] ? "selected":"";?>` this check is not right. There should be one `$resrproxy['proxyname']` to compare with other actuall value.

Comment: <option value="<?php echo $resrproxy['proxyname'];?>"<?php echo $resrproxy['proxyname']== $resrproxy['proxyname'] ? "selected":"";?>><?php echo $resrproxy['proxyname'];?></option>  I did this but not working

Comment: The line you mentioned, change it to like this;
`<option value="<?php echo $resrproxy['proxyname'];?>" <?php echo $resrproxy['proxyname'] == $pname ? "selected":"";?>><?php echo $resrproxy['proxyname'];?></option>`. I hope it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You've to compare `$resrproxy['proxyname']` value with `$pname`. Your code should be like this:

```
// your code

<select name="proxy" id="proxy" class="required input">
    <option value="">Select</option>

    <?php
        $result = $objfetch->fetch_proxy("*","where account_id='".$_SESSION['account_id']."' ");
        foreach($result as $key=>$resrproxy){
            $option = "<option value=\"{$resrproxy['proxyname']}\"";
            if(isset($pname)){
                if($pname == $resrproxy['proxyname']){
                    $option .= " selected=\"selected\"";
                }
            }
            $option .= ">{$resrproxy['proxyname']}</option>";
            echo $option;
        } 
    ?>
</select> 

// your code   `
```

Comment: @soni8010 I think the problem is because of this header line, `header("location:".SITE_URL."index.php?view=default_proxy");`. Remove this line and test again.

Comment: @soni8010 [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) is used to send a raw HTTP header to the browser. Whenever browser requests a page to the server, before server responds, it first sends the headers i.e what browser can expect next and browser can render itself accordingly, and then server sends the actual page.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <td>
  <select name="proxy" id="proxy" class="required input">
  <option value="">Select</option>

  <?php
  $result = $objfetch->fetch_proxy("*","where account_id='".$_SESSION['account_id']."' and `proxy_default`='1'");
  $pname=$result[0]['proxyname'];

  $result = $objfetch->fetch_proxy("*","where account_id='".$_SESSION['account_id']."' ");
  foreach($result as $key=>$resrproxy)
  {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $resrproxy['proxyname'];?>"<?php echo $resrproxy['proxyname']==$pname ? "selected":"";?>><?php echo $resrproxy['proxyname'];?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
  </td>
```